# Graph theory, $n$ people sitting around table

Tags: graphs, combinatorics

$n$ people want to have dinner together around a table for $k$ nights so that no person has the same neighbor twice.

1. How big can $k$ be in terms of $n$?
2. Does everybody get to sit next to everybody else?
3. How many seating arrangements are there?

Comment: What have you tried?  Have you tried working through some examples for small values of $k,n$ to see if you spot a pattern?  On this site, we expect you to make a serious effort before asking and to show us in the question you've tried.  Also, what does this have to do with computer science -- why isn't this a pure math question?  On this site, we expect you to articulate the connection to computer science in the question, if it's not obvious (otherwise Math.SE might be more suitable; you can click "flag" to ask the moderators to migrate it if you wish, but don't cross-post).

Answer (score 3):

*Point 3.* If the seats are unlabelled, the number of arrangements is $\frac{(n-1)!}{2}$.

*Explanation*: put a hat on one of the person and take it as the leader. Then you have $n-1$ choices for the person to his right and so on. But each arrangement is counted twice if you consider that circular arrangement $(a,b,c,d)$ is the same as the circular arrangement $(a,d,c,b)$.

*Point 2.* Answer is no. Take four people. They can only share one meal in your conditions. The people facing each-other will never eat side by side :-(

*Point 1.* You basically want to partition the edges of the complete graph on $n$ vertices into $k$ hamiltonian cycles. An obvious upper bound is then that $nk \leq {n \choose 2}$ so that $k \leq \left\lfloor \frac{n-1}{2} \right\rfloor$. This upper bound is met when $n$ is a prime number (take a first cycle then people at distance 2 then people at distance 3...)